JMeter does not create output folder
JMeter version: 5.0
Environment: Linux Server
I have JMeter test plan which sends 100 000 requests to my service I want to stress test. However there is an issue when script runs this test plan with:
./jmeter -n -t testName.jmx -l report_timestamp.csv -e -o report_timestamp_dir
For some reason JMeter does not create a directory where he should put html, but create a file report_timestamp_dir without extension.
I tried to run a much smaller test ( 200 requests) and output directory was created successfully. I also ran the first test plan ( with 100 000 requests) on my Windows PC, the folder created, however JMeter or Windows itself runs out of available ports and I am getting:
Address already in use error for the 20% of requests.

Take a look at jmeter.log file, it should contain the reason for report creation failure. Most probably for larger tests you might need to adjust JMeter memory settings.
With regards to Address already in use it means that JMeter runs out of available TCP sockets so you might want to amend your operating system TCP protocol settings, i.e. enable socket reuse, increase range of ephemeral ports
From JMeter side you can set httpclient.reset_state_on_thread_group_iteration to false, it will reduce the number of network connections created by JMeter
